# Copy selected items from ListView1 to ListView2

Tags: c#

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

I have got one populated ListView and trying to get the selected items into another ListView. The code I've got doesn't produce any errors, neither does it
display any of the selected items.

Thanks in advance.

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
     string s = "    Search Via Forename";
     int result = 0;
     int count = 0;
     result = string.Compare(textBox1.Text, s);

     if ((result == 0) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))){
            MessageBox.Show("Please input forename...");
            return;
     }

     foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items){
           if (item.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower())){
               count++;
               item.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
               item.ForeColor = Color.White;
               statusBar1.Panels[2].Text = "Found: " + count.ToString();
           } else {
               item.BackColor = Color.White;
               item.ForeColor = Color.Black;
           }
     }

     if (count > 1){
         listView2.Visible = true;
         foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items){
             listView2.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Does the if statement in your foreach return true more than once? And the if statement count > 1, maybe you want to change it to count > 0

Comment: you are not adding selected items

Comment: count in this case, only refers to the number of items found in ListView1, after the search criteria is checked against all items in ListView1. What I am trying to do is take the items found and put them into ListView2

Answer (score 0):

`if (count > 1){` should be `if (count > 0){` or `if (count >= 1){` ... in case there is only one match present. Moreover, don't see you are adding selected items

Answer (score 0):

why dont you do the clone directly in the first foreach?

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
    if(item.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower()))
        listView2.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
```

As you are doing it now, you dont select any item in the first list, only changing colors. Try using the `SelectedIndices` or `SelectedItems` properties.

Comment: Is it possible you could elaborate some more?

Comment: it depends what exactly you want to achieve: if you simply want to copy the found items to listView2, then use my snippet. If you also want to select the found items in listView1, you have to use e.g. `listView1.SelectedIndices.Add(*foundIndex*);`

Comment: I suppose I 'll Have to find all found index first?

Comment: I hate to be such a pain but I tried your code:- foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
    if(item.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower()))
        listView2.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone()); and it didn't work... it produce a blank listview2

Comment: I am convinced I am not displaying the results.. so I am going to investigate

Comment: have you tried debugging it step by step? Does it ever go into line 3 of my snippet (meaning: is the if clause true at least once)? If not: Check the debug values of `item.Text` and `textbox1.Text`

Comment: sorry... I am not familiar with the debug

Comment: try this if you use VisualStudio: https://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging
Debugging is one of the basic things you should know about!

Comment: Thanks... I'll have a look